# python-scrapy project to return list of urls, and scrape content inside of urls

Tags: python, scrapy

Currently trying to scrape this (page: 'https://sportschatplace.com/nba-picks') for a project with scrapy spiders for each game url and then go into each game's page and get more information inside.

When I run it, it just returns with no pages scraped. Any help would be appreciated. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
class GameSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'games'
    allowed_domains = ['sportschatplace.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://sportschatplace.com/nba-picks'
    ]
    def parse(self, response):
        games = response.css("div.home-a").extract_first()
        for g in games:
            url = urljoin(response.url, g)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.parse_game)

    def parse_game(self, response):
        for info in response.css('div.gutter'):
            yield {
                'game_teams': info.css('p.heading-sub').extract_first(), #check if these are correct before running
                'game_datetime': info.css('h2.heading-sub').extract_first(),
                'game_line': info.css('h3.heading-sub').extract_first(),
                # 'game_text': info.css('   ').extract(),
                'game_pick': info.css('h3.block mt1 dark-gray').extract(),
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
games = response.css("div.home-a").extract_first()
```

`div.home-a` contains multiple `divs`, and you are extracting the first one and also `extract_first()` convert that `div` into a string.

What i got from the link is that, your css is not giving you what you want.

Try this

```
css = '[itemprop="url"]::attr(href)'
games = response.css(css).extract()    #list of game urls
```